# repeating and missing number problem failing for unknown test cases

Tags: arrays, math

I was trying to solve the "Repeating and missing number" problem in InterviewBit.

Question URL : https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/repeat-and-missing-number-array/

The code is working fine in local and even in InterviewBit's custom input. But, failing when I submit the code.

Could someone help me with this?

```
    public class MissingRepatingNumberFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //int[] inputArray = null; // Test case #1 - Null input array
        //int[] inputArray = {}; // Test case #2 - empty array
        int[] inputArray = {3, 1, 2, 5, 3}; // Test case #3 - normal test case
        //int[] inputArray = {1,1,2}; // Test case #4 - minimal sized array

        int[] result = new int[2];

        MissingRepeatingNumberSolution solutionObject = new MissingRepeatingNumberSolution();

        result = solutionObject.repeatedNumber(inputArray);
    }
}

 class MissingRepeatingNumberSolution {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THE ARGUMENTS WITH "final" PREFIX. IT IS READ ONLY
    public int[] repeatedNumber(final int[] inputArray) {
        long arraySum = 0;
        long arraySquareSum = 0;
        int repeatedNumber = 0;
        int missingNumber = 0;

        for(int num : inputArray) {
            long lNum = num;
            arraySum = arraySum + lNum;
            arraySquareSum = arraySquareSum + (lNum * lNum);
        }

        long arraySize = inputArray.length;
        long sumOfN = arraySize*(arraySize + 1)/2;
        long sumSquareOfN = 0; //(arraySize*(arraySize + 1)*(2 * (arraySize + 1)))/6;
        long loopIndex = 1;
        while(loopIndex <= arraySize) {
            sumSquareOfN = sumSquareOfN + loopIndex*loopIndex;
            loopIndex++;
        }

        System.out.println("arraySum : "+ arraySum);
        System.out.println("sumOfN : "+ sumOfN);

        System.out.println("\n arraySquareSum : "+ arraySquareSum);
        System.out.println("sumSquareOfN : "+ sumSquareOfN);

        System.out.println("\n (arraySquareSum - sumSquareOfN) : " + (arraySquareSum - sumSquareOfN));
        System.out.println("(arraySum - sumOfN) : " + (arraySum - sumOfN));/**/

        missingNumber = (int)(((arraySquareSum - sumSquareOfN)/(arraySum - sumOfN) - arraySum + sumOfN)/2);
        //repeatedNumber = missingNumber - (int)(sumOfN - arraySum);
        repeatedNumber = missingNumber + (int)(arraySum - sumOfN);
        System.out.println("missingNumber : " + missingNumber);
        System.out.println("RepeatedNumber : " + repeatedNumber);/**/

        return new int[]{repeatedNumber, missingNumber};
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't make links to an external site an indispensable part of your question. These links can easily disappear. Instead, copy or rewrite the essential parts of the question.

Comment: @JohanC Sure. Thanks, bro. Will follow it :)

Answer (score 0):

The site you link to, explicitly mentions to cope with overflows. You're calculating a sum of squares. In Java, a long usually has 64 bits with a maximum value of 2<sup>63</sup>-1. The sum of squares from 1 to n is `(n*(n+1)*(n+2))/6`. This overflows for n around 3810777.

If, however, somebody runs this code on a system where long would only be 32 bit, the overflow already happens for n around 2343. Let's suppose this isn't happening.

Maybe there is a problem with the 'repeated' and the 'missing' number are the same? Then you would be dividing by zero. But, in that case the 'missing' wouldn't be  missing, and the 'repeated' wouldn't be repeated. For safety, it would be better to test for division by zero.

To try to find counter examples, you could repeat following code for many different values:

```
long N = 100000;
long missingNumber = 99999;
long repeatedNumber = 1;

long sumSquareOfN = N * (N + 1)*(N + 2)/6;
long arraySquareSum = sumSquareOfN - missingNumber * missingNumber + repeatedNumber * repeatedNumber;
long sumOfN = N * (N + 1) / 2;
long arraySum = sumOfN - missingNumber + repeatedNumber;

missingNumber = ((arraySquareSum - sumSquareOfN) / (arraySum - sumOfN) - arraySum + sumOfN) / 2;
repeatedNumber = missingNumber + (arraySum - sumOfN);

System.out.println(missingNumber, repeatedNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably someone who is looking for Python solution.

```
arr = [3, 1, 2, 5, 3] --> output = [3, 4]
```

---

Solution 1: Using Math

---

```
def repMis(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    rep,mis =0,0
    natural_sum = (n*(n+1))// 2
    squared_sum = (n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)) //6 
    for ele in arr:
        natural_sum -= ele
        squared_sum -= ele*ele
    mis = (natural_sum + squared_sum// natural_sum) // 2
    rep = mis - natural_sum
    return [rep, mis]
```

---

Solution 2: Using set

---

```
def repMis(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    rep = sum(arr) - sum(set(arr))
    diff = sum(arr) - (n*(n+1))//2
    mis = rep - diff
    return [mis, rep]
```

---